# The reliability of haar detect object

Tags: opencv, cascade, object-detection

I'm making a program using `cvHaarDetectObjects()` function.

I want to check whether the detected objects from `cvHaarDetectObjects()` function is really the object that I want to find.

As far as I know, Cascade Detector doesn't provide any degree or ratio of accuracy. However, I know that the fifth parameter of `cvHaarDetectObjects()` is the standard of overlapped image.

How can I find how many times the detected object is overlapped?

Comment: Looking at the source it seems that the number of detections is stored anywhere. It just calculates it, checks it is above the threshold and forgets about it, I think (the code for this is a bit hard to follow).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to use labelled datasets. [This](http://www.cvpapers.com/datasets.html) particular link; otherwise you can use [this tool](http://web.mit.edu/vondrick/vatic/) from MIT to annotate your own dataset..

Hope this helps.

Comment: He is asking how best to find the number of times the detected object is overlapped. The best way to do this is to use labelled datasets.. The results can be compared with the ground truth and do analysis accordingly..

Comment: No. Where there is a single object `cvHaarDetectObjects()` will have a number of overlapped detections. If this number is less than `min_neighbors` the detection is dropped. For a detection that was kept, @user2910667 wants to know how many neighbors the detection had. A labelled dataset may tell you that there are three cars present, but it can't tell you that when a single car is present that `cvHaarDetectObjects()` will find 5 overlapping detections.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Mr. @B... gets the right point. By the way thank you all !